# Traveling with the first récepissé

Tags: schengen-visas, france

I arrived in France in September 2019 on PT. Talent Type D Visa (valid for 3 months 28/11/2019). My visa now is expired, but I have applied for the three-years Carte de Séjour from 24 September. They provided me with a Récépissé de Demande de Carte de Séjour which is valid up to 23/3/2020.

After manifold following-up, they said that the last status of my card is changed to "under making" from 5 December 2019, but I have to travel to Spain on 22 Dec. I am getting a letter from Préfecture in which it is mentioned that my card is under making and has passed the confirmation step.

With these documents whether I can travel in the Schengen area or not?

I bought my plane tickets because before they have said that my card will be ready on the first of November.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote that this is about immigration.  The question is asking about their trip to Spain.